# php5.6 setcookie return empty value

Tags: php, session-cookies, setcookie

I'm using php5.6, server Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)

I have set some cookie value, but when print it's empty

```
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "Cookie Value", time()+3600,"/");
print_r($_COOKIE);
```

Comment: reload the page

Comment: reload page - still the same , empty value

Comment: i tried on my pc, it works

Comment: I check on my phpinfo() , under PHP Variables section, there is no $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'] variable

Comment: Why are you setting a cookie with the name usually reserved for the PHP session? Are you using `session_start()` anywhere?